# How to get ACL working in CentOS?

Tags: centos, access-control-list

I have this line in fstab:

```
/dev/sda3  /  ext3  defaults  1  2
```

I supposed I should change it to:

```
/dev/sda3  /  ext3  defaults,acl  1  2
```

I also suppose I should run:

```
mount -t ext3 -o acl /dev/sda3 /
```

Oh, but I get an error that it's already mounted or "/" is busy. How do I do this without crashing the system?

Comment: Upvoted, the question was helpful to me; I saw that someone had downvoted without leaving a comment. If you downvote why not leave a comment so OP can edit his question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `remount` option to the `mount` command, for instance:

```
mount -o remount /
```

This will cause it to re-read `/etc/fstab` and apply your new options.

Comment: this will not make the system unusable? will it kick me out of ssh connection?

Comment: No and no. This is _very basic_ stuff here.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is. I've messed with some mounting stuff in the past but spend most of my time on programming. I have no idea what is actually going on when a filesystem is unmounted, but it sounds potentially disastrous. Just ran your command and now testing to see if my acl is working finally.